# media_internet_get_provider(): Unable to handle the provided embed string or URL

Tags: 7, media

**Drupal 7 instance/Media 2.x module won't play nice with media on various internet services (youtube, vimeo, etc.).**

Originally (media 1.x) it worked with Media:YouTube & Media:Vimeo. I disabled these and tried Media:oEmbed. Still, my instance won't recognize the service calls.

This is the function that fails in Media/media_internet_get_provider for Vimeo:

```
function media_internet_get_provider($embed_string) {
  foreach (media_internet_get_providers() as $class_name => $nothing) {
    $p = new $class_name($embed_string);
    if ($p->claim($embed_string)) {
      return $p;
    }
  }
  throw new MediaInternetNoHandlerException(t('Unable to handle the provided embed string or URL.'));
}
```

It's the original code. 
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot/fix would be appreciated.